# docker file, failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref

Tags: react-native, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to dockerize a react-native app with expo. And the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file are in the root folder: dwl-frontend.

So this is the dockerfile:

```
# pull base image
FROM node:14.13.1-buster-slim


ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV


ARG PORT=19006
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT 19001 19002


ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH /home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
RUN npm i --unsafe-perm --allow-root -g npm@latest expo-cli@latest


RUN mkdir /opt/dwl_frontend
WORKDIR /opt/dwl_frontend
ENV PATH /opt/dwl_frontend/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn install


WORKDIR /opt/dwl_frontend/app

COPY ./ ./ 

ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "run", "web"]
CMD ["web"]
```

And docker-compose file:

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  dwl_frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "19006:19006"
      - "19001:19001"
      - "19002:19002"

    healthcheck:
      disable: true


But when I do a `docker-compose build`

I get this error:
```

### => ERROR [dwl_frontend 6/9] RUN yarn                                                                                                                          57.2s

> [dwl_frontend 6/9] RUN yarn:
> 0.577 yarn install v1.22.5
> 0.638 [1/4] Resolving packages...
> 1.023 [2/4] Fetching packages...
> 55.75 info fsevents@2.3.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
> 55.75 info "fsevents@2.3.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
> 55.76 error babel-plugin-module-resolver@5.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 16". Got "14.13.1"
> 55.76 error Found incompatible module.
> 55.76 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

---

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

```
Question: what I have to change?
```

Comment: That error message says to me that there isn't a `dwl_frontend` subdirectory of the current directory (more specifically the `build: { context: }` directory).  Does it exist, or is all of the application content in the current directory?

Comment: Oke, sorry, my mistake, the directory structure is like: C:\repos\DWL_frontend - with all the files in it. So in the DWL_frontend folder there are the dockerfile and the docker-compose file. And I build the container like: PS C:\repos\DWL_frontend> docker-compose build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand side of Dockerfile `COPY` statements is relative to the build-context directory (except that it can never go to a parent or sibling of that directory).  In your example, you specify `build: { context: . }`, and you indicate in a comment that all of the source files and the Compose file are in this same directory.  In this case you should use `.` as the path on the left-hand side of `COPY`, or leave it out entirely.  (It doesn't matter that the directory happens to be named `dwl_frontend`.)

```bash
WORKDIR /opt/dwl_frontend       # automatically creates the directory
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./  # from the current host directory
RUN yarn install

COPY ./ ./                      # current host directory into current image directory
CMD ["yarn", "run", "web"]
```

Your `volumes:` mounts will have the same problem.  However, their effect will be to hide everything in the image, which means the image you'll eventually deploy will be completely untested.  I'd recommend deleting the `volumes:` block entirely.

Comment: Aha, yes.  (The question has `package-lock.json` and I just copied that.)

Comment: #David Maze. Ah, I am using a other node from FROM. And now I can build the image. Thank you